# Clustering strings according to multiple string similarity ratings

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-cleaning, similarity, unsupervised-learning, sentence-similarity

I have a list of ~75000 strings that represent suburb names. These strings are often misspelled or are shortened variations. The list was captured manually over decades so do not underestimate how dirty this dataset is.

My goal is to find which of these strings belong to a suburb that I'm interested in i.e which of these strings were meant to be "HUMEWOOD" but were instead written as "HWOOD"/"HUMEWOOD STRAND"/"HUMWOOD" etc. Other suburbs have similar names such as "HUMERAIL" or "SHERWOOD" which score quite high for substring similarity, but are not the same suburb. I've used various string similarity algorithms and the results are OK, except that some algorithms are better suited to spelling mistakes (Levenstein)and other are better suited to finding the shortened variations (longest common substring).

I thought of plotting two normalised similarity ratings for each string and then using a clustering algorithm to find the strings that are describing my suburb. So I've got a similarity rating according to two different algorithms for each string like this:

[String similarity ratings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZqEC.png)

Now I'd like to use a clustering algorithm to group the strings that might represent my suburb, plotting these ratings results in the following:

[Plotting two string similarity ratings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak3om.png)

Obviously there are many combinations of string similarity algorithms I can use, and many clustering algorithms that can be used on those combinations. So before I take a deep dive into which combinations work best I'd like to know:
Is this even a viable approach? I can't find any implementations similar to this and I'm sure there must be a good reason. Maybe I'm over-complicating this entirely,in which case I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: I recently had good results using https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity, which uses the Dice coefficient instead of Levenshtein distance.

Comment: I'm more interested in knowing whether I can use clustering on two different similarity algorithms, as opposed to which similarity algorithm to use, if that makes sense?

Comment: "Calculated weighted average" is a simple way to combine multiple ratings, and from there you can go as high into number theory as you can stomach.